# Как выбрать определённый текст и загрузить на форму?

Tags: c#

Привет. Мне нужно выбрать текст из файла и создать в форме панель которая покажет этот текст. Создал метод по записи в txt.

```
       public void AddSp(string name, int size, string URL)
    {
        string[] lines = { "[RUN_ADDMANGA] " + "name = " + name + " " + "size = " + size + " " + "URL = " + URL + " " + "[END_ADDMANGA]" + Environment.NewLine };
        File.WriteAllLines(_path, lines);
    }
```

А вот как выгружать на панель  не знаю, причем так, что бы выгрузилась только name,size,URl;

Comment: Вам для начала следует определиться с UI-фреймворком.

Comment: @VladD Я так понимаю он мне понадобится для отображения ? А какой Вы посоветуете ?

Comment: Ну да, понадобится. Мне сложно советовать. Из двух встроенных (WinForms и WPF) WPF намного более продвинутый, но его надо учить и разбираться. Выбор за вами.

Comment: @VladD Я покопался и нашёл XMT ui framervork. Пока буду разбираться с ним. Но не могли бы вы предоставить пример с WinForms? Если Вас не затруднит.

Comment: Ну вот например официальный пример: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd492132.aspx

Comment: @VladD Вы возможно не поняли. Как же мне загрузить информацию ?

Comment: Ну почитайте и разберитесь, там разжёвано вплоть до кнопочек, на которые надо нажимать. Или подождите, пока подтянутся специалисты по WinForms и напишут пример.